# iOS widget reload placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storekit, widgetkit

I have a purchasable widget in my iOS app.

When the user hasn't purchased it, I show it with faded opacity and a padlock.

When the user completes the purchase, I reload all the widgets so the padlock disappears and the opacity returns to normal.

```swift
// To reload all widgets, I do:
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

But, even though the widgets are reloaded correctly on the home screen, the placeholders remain the same.

The placeholder of the purchased widget continues to display the padlock and the wrong opacity.

How can I reload the placeholders as well?